# Prevent Excel from making links to external macro functions in formulas absolutely

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

There are two workbooks: The view **foo.xlsm** and the control **bar.xlsm** which gets loaded from the **foo.xlsm** with the *Workbooks.Open()-Method* and includes the VBA-Code necessary for the view. It does so because there are multiple possible paths to the **bar.xlsm** which have to be checked prior.

```
Set wC = Workbooks.Open("path\bar.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True, Editable:=False, AddToMru:=False)
```

In **foo.xlsm** there is a formula referencing to a macro function from **bar.xlsm**:

```
=bar.xlsm!functionName(parameter)
```

The problem is that on every startup excel modifies that link to the last path from which the **bar.xlsm** got loaded successfully, e.x.:

```
='C:/Users/X/Desktop/bar.xlsm'!functionName(parameter)
```

This behaviour is unwanted because the path of **bar.xlsm** can and will change. How to prevent excel from making this link absolutely?

Comment: did you tried using a variable for the `path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have found an uncomplicated workaround. I call the desired method using a wrapper function in the view workbook:

```
Public Function functionWrapper() As Integer
   functionWrapper = Application.Run("bar.xlsm!functionName(parameter)")
End Function
```

The wrapper function is called inside the desired cell formula as follows:

```
=functionWrapper(parameter)
```